# How do I REPALCE just the state in the current location with React Router

Tags: react-router

I'm curious if there is a good way to replace just the state in the current location. It's a pattern that I do often and it always requires creating a new location object from the location and I feel like there must be a better way to achieve this.

```
import React from 'react';
import withRouter from 'react-router/lib/withRouter';

class Component extends React.Component {
  updateLocationState(value) {
    const newLocation = Object.assign({}, this.props.location, {
      state: Object.assign({}, this.props.location.state, {
        myKey: value,
      }),
    });
    this.props.router.replace(newLocation);
  }
  ...
}

export default withRouter(Component);
```

This feels very verbose and it copies the location key which feels wrong. Is there a better pattern for this?

I'm on react-router v2.6